# There was a problem collecting hot code using the Baseline Profile

Tags: android, baseline-profile

I hope you can help me, I created the Benchmark module in Android Studio, he has helped me set up the required things, my project is multi-channel, package name I have set and correct: the code is:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalBaselineProfilesApi::class)
class TrivialBaselineProfileBenchmark {
    // [START baseline_profile_basic]
    @get:Rule
    val baselineProfileRule = BaselineProfileRule()

    @Test
    fun startup() = baselineProfileRule.collectBaselineProfile(
        packageName = " com.xxx.xxx,
        profileBlock = {
            startActivityAndWait()
            device.waitForIdle()
        }
    )
    // [END baseline_profile_basic]
}
```

[image]

Then I get the following error when I use it:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the library can't find the app with the specified `packageName`.

It is quite common to define some suffix based on build variant, so make sure your build variant uses the same package name as the `packageName` parameter.